# EWS - Timezone issue with getUserAvailability method

Tags: java, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010, ewsjavaapi

I am using EWS Java API 1.2 and Exchange 2010 SP2 for my application.

With `getUserAvailability` method I am getting the meeting start-end times and free-busy statuses of the requested users. The problem here is that this method returns date according to the UTC time zone even if I initialize `ExchangeService` instance with another timezone. I see in API codes (`EwsUtilities.java` class) that line:

```
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

So it seems that the API ignores the timezone in requests. I also read that there was a bug for Exchange Server 2007 about timezones. Is it still broken for 2010 and 1.2 API version?

Answer (score 0):

Any thing you retrieve from exchange would be in "UTC" (GMT-00) timezone, so you need to convert that into a local timezone you require.